# How prove there exsit $M$ such $a_{n}\le M$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Define sequence $a_{n}$ and such 
$a_{1}=a$ where $a$ is postive constant, and such
$$(a_{n+1})^3=\sqrt{a_{n}}+a_{n}$$
show that: there exsit constant $M$,such for any postive integer
$n$,have $a_{n}\le M$

maybe consider
$$a^3_{n+1}-a^3_{n}=\sqrt{a_{n}}+a_{n}-a^3_{n}$$
let $\sqrt{a_{n}}=t>0$,then
$$a^3_{n+1}-a^3_{n}=t+t^2-t^6=t(1+t-t^5)$$
following maybe can't works.

idea 2
$$|a^3_{n+1}-a^3_{n}|=|a_{n}+\sqrt{a_{n}}-a_{n-1}-\sqrt{a_{n-1}}|=|a_{n}-a_{n-1}|1+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a_{n}}+\sqrt{a_{n-1}}}|$$
then also following can't works

Comment: Maybe using the graph of $y=(\sqrt{x} + x)^{1/3}$ works.

Comment: @i707107,How use this function?

Comment: You can show that $x = \sqrt[3]{x+\sqrt{x}}$ has exactly one positive solution $x = \alpha \approx 1.36$. Then show that if $a_1 = a < \alpha$, $a_n$ is monotonically increasing to $\alpha$ and if $a_1 = a > \alpha$, $a_n$ is monotonically decreasing to $\alpha$. After showing these facts, pick $M = \max(a_1,\alpha)$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the sequence $$x_{n+1}^6 = x_n + x_n^2$$ instead.

Let $\alpha$ be the largest root of $x^5 - x - 1 = 0$ ($x^5 - x - 1$ increases in region $x \ge \alpha$).

Now if $x_n \gt \alpha$, then we must have that $x_{n+1} \le x_n$.

We also must have that $x_{n+1} \ge \alpha$

This shows that it is bounded.